# Installed Cordova on Mac, but PhoneGap is the only one I can find

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, cordova

I use:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

to install Cordova on my Mac, and here is the last few lines of the command line generated:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@3.4.1-0.1.0 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── semver@2.0.11
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── plist-with-patches@0.5.1 (xmlbuilder@0.4.3, xmldom@0.1.19)
├── shelljs@0.1.4
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.8)
├── xcode@0.6.6 (node-uuid@1.3.3, pegjs@0.6.2)
├── elementtree@0.1.5 (sax@0.3.5)
├── npmconf@0.1.13 (once@1.3.0, inherits@2.0.1, osenv@0.0.3, ini@1.1.0, mkdirp@0.3.5, nopt@2.2.0, config-chain@1.1.8)
├── tar@0.1.19 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7, fstream@0.1.25)
├── request@2.21.0 (json-stringify-safe@4.0.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, qs@0.6.6, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, cookie-jar@0.3.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, http-signature@0.9.11, hawk@0.13.1, form-data@0.0.8)
└── plugman@0.21.0 (bplist-parser@0.0.5, nopt@1.0.10, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.3.0, glob@3.2.9, request@2.22.0, npm@1.3.4)
```

So I followed the output information and went into the folder `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules` but there is no Cordova, only Phonegap. I also tried another folder `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/`, but under it I cannot find Cordova either, PhoneGap is the one under it.

How can I install Cordova properly on a Mac?

### Update

I searched for "cordova" inside the system and found:

```
/Users/mbp13/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova
/Users/mbp13/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.3.0/bin/templates/scripts/cordova
/Users/mbp13/.npm/connect-phonegap/0.10.0/package/lib/middleware/cordova
/Users/mbp13/.npm/connect-phonegap/0.10.0/package/res/middleware/cordova
/Users/mbp13/.npm/cordova
/Users/mbp13/.npm/cordova/3.4.1-0.1.0/package/bin/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/.bin/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/res/middleware/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/e2e/fixtures/platforms/android/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/spec/projects/android_one/cordova
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/spec/projects/android_one/cordova/lib/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/.bin/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/lib/middleware/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/res/middleware/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `cordova -v`?

Comment: hi @AndrewLively the system doesn't recognise cordova so if I typed cordova -v, it will not recognise it either.

Comment: What, specifically, to you get when you do so? `cordova: command not found` or something else?

Comment: Also, if you `ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules`, is Cordova in there?

Comment: hi @KerriShotts yes, it says command not found. and I have mentioned that under "the folder /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules but there is no cordova only phonegap". What could be the issue?

Comment: On my Mac (OSX 10.9), the location you reference has neither Cordova nor Phonegap. Do *you* have anything in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` (note that this is a little different than your path)? I'm just trying to find out where Cordova is on your system.

Comment: Also, at your root directory, try `sudo find -name cordova`. That way we can see if you have it anywhere on your system.

Comment: hi @KerriShotts thank you for your help. I tried:sudo find -name cordova, it says: "find illegal option --n".  So I changed to : sudo find cordova, the result is: "find: cordova: No such file or directory"

Comment: I must've typed that wrong. Try `sudo find / -name cordova`. In case SO nukes it, there should be a forward slash between `find` and `-name` with intervening spaces. That should search the entire volume for cordova.

Comment: hi @KerriShotts , the command works. And I found some, please see my update. thx